# WebGL Canvas Text Jitter

Tags: text, graphics, html5-canvas, dart-html, webgl2

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

So I'm trying to achieve a typewriter effect in WebGL. Currently, I use a 2D canvas to generate the text then I turn that into a texture for WebGL. All that works and the text looks fine. But when I try to do my effect–by adding one character of text to a line and rendering–there is a slight but noticeable jittering of the characters, it seems something to do with the kerning, but I'm not sure.

Is there some setting in canvas that I could use to mitigate this?

Comment: If you give WebGL the same inputs it will draw the same thing so when you say it jitters that suggests that maybe you aren't giving it the same inputs for previous letters the next time you draw?

Comment: Maybe, I'm pretty sure everything is the same but adding a letter to the end of the string then drawing it. Watching the characters they move slight amounts, some closer to others and such.